# Force Wordpress to generate post slug from title only on specific custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

I use the code below to force WordPress to generate post slug from post title even when a user define a different slug or duplicate another slug but i want this to only affect a specific post type called **job_listing** but unfortunately it affects all post type on my site.

```
function myplugin_update_slug( $data, $postarr ) {
if ( ! in_array( $data['post_status'], array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) {
    $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $data['post_title'] );
}

return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'myplugin_update_slug', 99, 2 );
```

How do i target only a specific post type called **job_listing** with the above code without affecting other post types

Can somebody help me amend this code to suit my need?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you expect to use duplicate slugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs `$data` contains `post_type` so you should be able to use this:

```
function myplugin_update_slug( $data, $postarr ) {
    if ( $data['post_type'] === 'job_listing' && ! in_array( $data['post_status'], array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) {
        $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $data['post_title'] );
    }

    return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'myplugin_update_slug', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this resolved the issue for me. The solution may have been simple but I am actually in php learning stage. I hope to be a pro too some day.